# DateInterval string Problems

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I'm trying to do a math problem using datetime in php. 
The problem that the string that I'm creating is dynamic. If I add as a static string it runs fine, but If I make the string dynamic it fails. Here's a code example.

```
 $now = new DateTime();
$datetime_interval = 'P' . $filledOrder->hours . 'H'; // hours comes from an object
$now->add(new DateInterval($datetime_interval));
```

If I add static string to DateInterval is working fine`enter code here`

```
$now->add(new DateInterval('P10H'));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error? If `$filledOrder->hours` was null or empty that would lead to sth. like bad format error. Also note your (static) format is incorrect: From the interval spec: "If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T". So it should be 'PT' . $hours . 'H'

Comment: No I'm not getting an error and when I debug I see that the property of that object does have a value

Comment: macghriogair you are right. It work's now thank you so much. Just spent an hour on this. Thanks again

Comment: glad that it helped :)

Comment: Did you try use [**Carbon**](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)?

Comment: Can't use Carbon on this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should consider entering full string as format like this way.

P0Y0DT10H0M

Comment: Did you tried this solution? Replace whatever part you want with variable.